# Webcam of Ubuntu 18.04 camera is on but there is opposite side appearence

Tags: webcam

```
(cheese:2126): cheese-WARNING **: 10:52:37.465: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: gstbasesink.c(2902): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
```

There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
For this what is the solution?

Comment: I could not catch what does the **opposite side appearance** phrase mean.

Answer (score 0):

Using the "nodrop=1" option from the command line worked for me:

```
cheese uvcvideo nodrop=1
```

If this doesn't work, then you can try enabling the same option in the uvc kernel module as follows:

Add the following to /etc/modprobe.d/uvcvideo.conf:

```
options uvcvideo nodrop=1
```

After you added that line, reload the module:

```
sudo rmmod uvcvideo && sudo modprobe uvcvideo
```

References:

1. https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=223106
2. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UVC